# Setting backButtonDisplayMode to minimal breaks large title animation

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a ViewController featuring a large title. I want the back button to have a minimal display mode, but this causes the large title animation to become balky. This issue occurs when the view appears on the screen under the popped view controller.

Here is the code with the proper animation for the title (the title apears smoothly as if from the secound view controller nav bar)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    title = "Title"
    navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .default
  }
}
```

[image]

And this is the problematic animation (the title apears as if it comes from the distance of the first view controller navigation bar).

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        title = "Title"
        navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
      }
    }
```

[image]

Is there something that can be done, so I'll have a minimal backButtonDisplayMode, but the default animation?

Comment: Your question is unclear, You have copied same code twice. Can you share a sample git project or code?

Comment: Apology, I've updated the code. One of them should have been .default instead of .minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's quite difficult to understand what you're after (and the fact that the two snippets provided are identical) I will try to treat this question as "I want to get the first result - but without a back title".

A few things to note here:

- `minimal` here just means "No back button title - just display the chevron"
- Since the snippets are identical (probably by error) I assume that the first one is just *without* the `minimal` setting (because we can see the back title in the second VC).
- The only difference in the two recordings is that in the first one (the one with the back title) there is a transition *from* the back button to the large title *with* an opacity change (fade). I assume that this fade is what you ultimately want.

Now, the framework here notices that there is nothing to transition *from* (back button title) so it *omits* the opacity change.

And there is nothing we can do about it... unless we are willing to work around it by exploiting what we already know.

So we think... What if we drop the `minimal` and just set `navigationItem.backButtonTitle = ""` it should work, right? Well no (and this is quite familiar to developers with extensive UIKit experience) because the system treats empty strings as no button title present at all.

Which leads us (you guessed it) to use a space for the back title:

```
// Note that `backButtonDisplayMode` must not set up to `minimal`
navigationItem.backButtonTitle = " "
```

That ultimately produces:

[image]

Comment: I've updated my code. The first snippet had .default instead of .minimal. Way to go on the investigative skills! :))
This is aaaaalmost what I am looking for.
Please check out the screencast from the Apple Music app. You can see that the "Listen Now" animation starts from around x = -10 of the screen and the fade-in is slower. Is there a way to achieve that? Because my title is a bit long so it doesn't look good

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExcHZoenJpbXc4b2dtb3ZydGdpOHdpYTFwYzlvMzJqMzJjZnBjM2p2NSZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9Zw/PLtFHbMwTYl4RUo6pA/giphy-downsized-large.gif

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExNzFnbWUzcWFtZmFkN3V3bnd1OTQ2cmZhY3N1YXJvN28yczU2MXgxbCZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9Zw/xRWthgevkTG7Pc2zfv/giphy.gif

Comment: @Luda Thanks! I don't think (but I would be glad to be wrong about it) that there is a canonical way to change the transition params for the large title. The more I look to the Apple Music gif, the more I believe that it's a custom label that matches the style of the large style and having a custom interactive transition driving it (my suspicion comes from the fact that the title is not overlaid during the transition, like it does in my example when the title is really long, but _clipped_ underneath).

Comment: Thank you for your kind nd in-depth explanation

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to [customize the transition animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html) in your navigation bar.

Something like this:

[image]

[source](https://iosexample.com/a-custom-navigation-bar-for-each-view-controller/)

For this you can check this code in [Github](https://github.com/demalex/NavBarAnimation/tree/animation-implementation/NavBarAnimation) (its old but will do the trick)

Or this newer code on [Github swiftui-navigation-transitions](https://github.com/davdroman/swiftui-navigation-transitions)